# Why am I (low rep user) able to downvote questions/answers on this community?

Tags: discussion, voting

I am a low reputation user (103 points)  on this community. However, I am able to downvote questions and answers. I thought I needed 125 points for downvoting. On other communities, I need 125 points for downvoting but not on this one, why?